# Java: Generics return statement syntax

Tags: java, generics, syntax

I'm struggeling to understand the syntax of this return statement, especially the leading C:

```
 <C>
```

I'm quite new to generics, but I know the basics. Can anyone explain this?

```
public abstract <C> CustomMap<K, C> map(Function<? super V, ? extends C> f)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`<C>` is not a return type. It's a declaration of a new generic type variable that can be used only by the `map` method.

Since the `map` method appears to have additional generic type variables - `V` and `K` - that are not declared in the same way as `C`, we can assume that `V` and `K` are declared as generic type variables at the class level (of the class that contains this method). If They are not, `V` and `K` will be treated as regular identifiers (i.e. the compiler will expect to find classes having the names `V` and `K`).

Based on the signature of your method and its return type (`CustomMap`), I can assume that this method belongs to some class that implements the `Map<K,V>` interface. It accepts a `Function` that receives an instance of type `V` and returns an instance of type `C`, so it's reasonable to assume that it converts a `Map<K,V>` to a `Map<K,C>` (i.e. the keys remain the same and the values are transformed).